# Straight vs Partial derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Does it make sense to write $\frac{d}{dx}u(x,t)$ or can one only write $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}u(x,t)$?

Comment: I believe you can write either, but they have very different meanings. If you don't see how different they are then you probably really mean $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} u(x,t)$.

Comment: Fixed typos. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For convention's sake, I'll pretend you asked about $\frac{d}{dt}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$. It's the same exact question this way, and you'll see the reason for the change in notation afterwards.

Getting to the point, say you have a function of two variables $$u:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^k\atop (x,t)\mapsto u(x,t)$$

For example, let $k=1$ and we have a scalar field (which we can think of as dependent on "position" $x$ and time $t$, if we wish). Now consider a real function $x(t)$ (forgive me for using the same letter $x$ for a completely new term). This determines a path through $\Bbb R^2: \gamma (t) =(x(t),t)$. We can compose the two functions to get a real function of $t$: $u\circ\gamma$. Now, this is a sort of liberal use of notation, but we can "identify" $u$ with $u\circ\gamma$. Now the derivative of $u$ is $$\frac{d}{dt}u = \frac{d}{dt}u(x(t),t) = \frac{\partial u }{\partial x}x'(t) + \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$$

You can see for yourself that both $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ and $\frac{d}{dt}$ are applied to $u$, to mean different things. Again, this is artificious notation (at least, I haven't seen it formalized), but it's usually just comfortable to write this way, so many people do.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ maybe considered as a quotient of two differentials, since $dy= y' \cdot dx$, whereas $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ is an indivisible symbol.

According to this, it's convinient to write such type of equations $\frac{d(f(g(x))}{dx}= \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{g}} \cdot \frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{x}}$

Comment: This is really mystic. Please compare with the classical
calculations:
$$\begin{gathered}
  f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},y \mapsto z = f(y) \hfill \\
  g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},x \mapsto y = g(x) \hfill \\
  f \circ g = \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},x \mapsto f \circ g(x) = f(g(x)) \hfill \\
  dz = f'(y)dy \Rightarrow \frac{{dz}}{{dy}} = f'(y) \hfill \\
  dy = g'(x)dx \Rightarrow \frac{{dy}}{{dx}} = g'(x) \hfill \\
  dz = f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x) \cdot dx \hfill \\
  \frac{{dz}}{{dx}} = f'(g(x)) \cdot g'(x) = f'(y) \cdot g'(x) = \frac{{dz}}{{dy}} \cdot \frac{{dy}}{{dx}} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$

Comment: @Frieder Yes, you must be right.

Actually,  is the $\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{dz}{dy} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}$  as appropriate as the notation with the partial formulas?

Comment: Partial derivatives come in, if we have more than one variable. And derivatives with respect to functions, this is handled in calculus of variations. Thank you! (I just wondered a little)